# Delete the string after the delimiter in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have simple problem. I was analyzing some data and came up with this problem.

Below is my value in a colomn:

```
www.mysite.come/api/Customer?id=12333&name=jack
www.mysite.come/api/Department?id=52365&name=COP
www.mysite.come/api/Customer?id=13333&name=mathew
```

etc

I want to filter this data something like this

```
www.mysite.come/api/Customer
 www.mysite.come/api/Department
www.mysite.come/api/Customer
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its just as simple as removing everything after, including, the `?` then this will do it:
`=LEFT(A:A,FIND("?", A1)-1)`

**Edit:** If you want to catch the `#VALUE!` error when there is no `?` simply use `IFERROR`:
`=IFERROR(LEFT(A:A,FIND("?", A1)-1), A1)`

Example rows:

```
www.mysite.come/api/Customer?id=12333&name=jack
www.mysite.come/api/Department?id=52365&name=COP
www.mysite.come/api/Customer?id=13333&name=mathew
```

Output:

```
www.mysite.come/api/Customer
www.mysite.come/api/Department
www.mysite.come/api/Customer
```

Comment: That's great!!! it worked. Just need one more help. If "?" not there in column then also result should appear.

Comment: What result do you want if there is no `?`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a combination of `FIND` and `LEFT`.

For example (where A1 contains your original value)

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND("?", A1) -1)
```

Comment: ...but @mmmmmpie got there first!

Answer (score 1):

The significance of your mention of filter is not clear to me but you might copy your data into another column, select the latter column and with Find/Replace Find what:

```
~?*
```

<kbd>Replace All</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Its a good idea to handle when when the column doesn't contain the "?". To do this  use the ISERROR() function as follows:

```
=LEFT(A2, IF(ISERROR(FIND("?",A2))=TRUE,LEN(A2), (FIND("?",A2)-1)))
```